# Finding array index of object in an array is affecting minification and uglification using grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-usemin

```
let index = $scope.fetchPanelAssessorDetails.findIndex
( assessor => assessor.name === assessorDet.name );
```

I tried fetching the index of the object using above code. It worked too, but it affects my minification and uglification of code using grunt. What is the solution to overcome this.

Comment: In order to provide a solution, we need a full description of the problem. Stating that “it affects my minification” is not helpful.